# Android convert String to HashMap

Tags: java, android, regex, json

I have a string that is something like this:

`[ { "1":33 }, { "2":30 }, { "3":15 }, { "4":23 }, ...{ "9":17 },... { "U":2 }, { "V":22 }, { "W":1 }, { "X":35 }, { "Y":6 }, { "Z":19 } ]`

The structure is `{"key":value}`. I need to convert this to a table/HashMap so that I can fetch values based on the key.

I tried using Gson but failed. Could there be a simpler method to do it like using some serialization?

TIA

Comment: this is in JSON format.. so use JSON and put those Json objects in HashMap

Comment: See my working code using only regex

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use this method I made:

```
public HashMap<String, Integer> convertToHashMap(String jsonString) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> myHashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
            JSONObject jObject = null;
            String keyString=null;
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                // beacuse you have only one key-value pair in each object so I have used index 0 
                keyString = (String)jObject.names().get(0);
                myHashMap.put(keyString, jObject.getInt(keyString));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return myHashMap;
    }
```

use:

```
String myString = "[ { \"1\":33 }, { \"2\":30 }, { \"3\":15 }, { \"4\":23 }, { \"9\":17 }, { \"U\":2 }, { \"V\":22 }, { \"W\":1 }, { \"X\":35 }, { \"Y\":6 }, { \"Z\":19 } ]";
HashMap<String, Integer> map = convertToHashMap(myString);
Log.d("test", map.toString());
```

you can also get all keys using `map.keySet()`

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "{ 1:33 }, { 2:30 }, { 3:15 }, { 4:23 }, { 9:17 }, { U:2 }, { V:22 }, { W:1 }, { X:35 }, { Y:6 }, { Z:19 }";
    String[] arr = s.split(", ");
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (String str : arr) {
        str = str.replace("{", "").replace("}", "");
        String[] splited = str.split(":");

        map.put(splited[0], Integer.parseInt(splited[1].trim()));

    }
    System.out.println(map);

}
```

Output:

```
{ 9=17,  Z=19,  Y=6,  X=35,  1=33,  3=15,  2=30,  W=1,  V=22,  4=23,  U=2}
```

Comment: he has a different initial string

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov that is not string what he wrote above .

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov What your code doing adding \ that is also not initial string.

Comment: Have you heard of escaping special characters? Try to define `String s = "{ "1":33 }"; in Java

Answer (score 0):

Write your own simple parser. Start reading each character from start, when you see a " then start treating next character start as start of key and at the occurrence of next " tak it key now at this point look for a : and then record value till you see a blank space or a }. Repeat this process again till you have read all characters in the string. This way if there are n characters then it will b solved in O(n)

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of objects, each one different (it has a different field). JSON parsers are going to have problems with that when talking about deserializing it to an object. The Gson users guide [specifically mentions this](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Collection-with-Objects-of-Arbitrary-Types).

You can use Gson, but you're going to have to use one of the methods they suggest. Creating a custom deserializer that returned a `Map` would be fairly straightforward. You need to go through the array, get each object, then get extract the field and the value:

```
// create this class so as not to affect other Map types:
class MyMap extends HashMap<String, Integer> {}

class MyMapDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<MyMap> 
{
    public MyMap deserialize(JsonElement je, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jdc) 
          throws JsonParseException 
    {
        JsonArray ja = je.getAsJsonArray();
        MyMap map = new MyMap();
        for (int i = 0; i < ja.size(); i++) 
        {
            JsonObject jo = ja.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
            Set<Entry<String, JsonElement>> set = jo.entrySet();
            for (Entry<String, JsonElement> e : set) 
            {
                map.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue().getAsInt());
            }
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

You use it via:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(MyMap.class, new MyMapDeserializer())
                .create();

MyMap mm = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyMap.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code using regex:

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    //!!Your string comes here, I escape double quoutes manually !!
    String str = "\"[ { \"1\":33 }, { \"2\":30 }, { \"3\":15 }, { \"4\":23 }, { \"9\":17 }, {\"U\":2 }, { \"V\":22 }, { \"W\":1 }, { \"X\":35 }, { \"Y\":6 }, { \"Z\":19 } ]\"";
    String regex = "\\{\\s*\"(\\w+)\":(\\d+)\\s*\\}";


    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        String key = matcher.group(1);
        String value = matcher.group(2);
        System.out.println(key + " " + value);
        map.put(key, value);
    }
```

prints:

```
1 33
2 30
3 15
4 23
9 17
U 2
V 22
W 1
X 35
Y 6
Z 19
```

**Note:** If you want `Map<String,Integer>` then change definition and use `Integer.parseInt()` to get integer from a String.